# How to remove incorrectly formatted rows from an imported CSV

Tags: r

I have a data file (a CSV) where some of the rows have been incorrectly separated. For example, I have a "Date" header where the only strings should be days of the week, but there are occasionally strings from other parts of the data file under this header. there aren't too many to where I need to worry about messing up the data if I remove them, so I would like to delete these rows as long as the data in that column isn't a day of the week. How should I do this?

Comment: the trick is to correctly format the CSV file.  Based on your description `there aren't too many to where I need to worry about messing up`  How do you expect others to answer this question without a small reproducible example?

Comment: The problem is the CSV file is an extract from my iMessage texts, so the texts themselves include all kinds of characters, which I believe is what messes up the imported table.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this with a simple script. I will demonstrate this with JS and the NodeJS runtime, although you could use the approach with any language.

I assume you can write a script like this in R, but you can use any language you like to generate the cleaned CSV. I am just trying to demonstrate the concept.

This script will parse each row of the CSV, and determine if the day field contains a valid day of the week by splitting on the CSV delimiter. If it does, it will append that row onto a new csv.

Assuming the csv dataset in data.csv looks something like this:

Car;Monday;\n
Ball;Bat;\n
Place;Wednesday;

The node script to parse this is as follows:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const file = fs.readFileSync('./data.csv', 'utf8')
const cleanedFile = './cleaned.csv'
file.split('\n').forEach(row => {
  const daysOfWeek = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'etc...']
  const fields = row.split(';')
  const day = fields[1]
  if (daysOfWeek.includes(day)) {
    fs.appendFile(cleanedFile, `${row}\n`, (err) => {
      if (err) throw new Error('There was a problem appending to the file')
    })
  }
})
```

This will generate a new csv called cleaned.csv, that would look like:

Car;Monday;\n
Place;Wednesday;